# Unable to find type WcfService1.FaultException, WcfService1, version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, enterprise-library

I have a simple WCF project, where I'm trying to use the Enterprise Library v6.0 and in the Enterprise Library Configuration I get this warning:

> *Unable to find type WcfService1.FaultException, WcfService1, version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null*.

I can't find the reason why PublicKeyToken=null,

I'm thinking this is the reason why I get this warning. Bellow you find my code:

**Service1.svc.cs**

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    [ExceptionShielding("Policy")]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        [FaultContract(typeof(FaultException))]
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            throw new Exception("message test");
        }        
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class FaultException : Exception
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Guid FaultID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string FaultMessage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**IService1.cs**

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(FaultException))]
        string GetData(int value);
    }
    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Enterprise Library Configuration**

[image: Unable to find type WcfService1.FaultException, WcfService1, version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]

Comment: Are you signing or delay-signing your service assembly?

Comment: @TomRedfern I'm not sure what that means but, i compiled the service and than i imported the dll with "add from file". If this isn't the right answer please tell me how to find this out, Thanks :)

Comment: If you imported the DLL from file are you certain the DLL contains the FaultException definition in it? Have you tried adding the actual project to the solution to see if the warning goes away? Even if there is a warning, if you run the solution, do errors thrown on the service propagate to the client as a FaultContract? If so then it's just a warning you can ignore.

Comment: @TomRedfern Yes - http://i.imgur.com/gwK2gQi.png